# Convert wstringstream to LPCWSTR

Tags: winapi, stringstream, lpcwstr

I am a beginner at Winapi and I am trying to convert wstringstream to LPCWSTR like this (inside WM_PAINT):

```cpp
wstringstream ws; 
ws << "my text" << endl; 
LPCWSTR myWindowOutput = ws.str().c_str();
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); 
TextOut(hdc, 150, 305, myWindowOutput, 10);
```

It only produces rubbish though, can somebody help? Thank you.

Comment: How are you trying to display the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LPCWSTR myWindowOutput = ws.str().c_str()` produces a temporary (the return value of the [str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) call), that's gone as soon as the full statement ends. Since you need the temporary, you need to move it down to the call, that eventually consumes it:

```
TextOutW(hdc, 150, 305, ws.str().c_str(), static_cast<int>(ws.str().length()));
```

Again, the temporary lives until the full statement ends. This time around, this is long enough for the API call to use it.

As an alternative, you could bind the return value of `str()` to a **const** reference<sup>1)</sup>, and use that instead. This may be more appropriate, since you need to use the return value twice (to get a pointer to the buffer, and to determine its size):

```
wstringstream ws;
ws << "my text" << endl;
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
const wstring& s = ws.str();
TextOutW(hdc, 150, 305, s.c_str(), static_cast<int>(s.length()));
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Why this works is explained under [GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most Important const”](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).*